# AWS IOT client connection using CredentialsProvider

Tags: spring-boot, aws-iot-core, spring-integration-mqtt

I am able to AWS IOT core using certificate and private key using below code

KeyStorePasswordPair pair = getKeyStorePasswordPair(certificateFilePath, privateKeyFilePath, keyAlgorithm);
if (pair != null) {
awsIotClient = new AWSIotMqttClient(clientEndpoint, clientId, pair.getKeyStore(),
pair.getKeyPassword());
}

above code work fine to development or POC but for the production env we should use AWS IAM credential or values from EKS. for this i am try below code

new AWSIotMqttClient(clientEndpoint, clientId, awsCredentialsProvider(), Regions.AP_SOUTH_1.getName());

but not able to get awsCredentialsProvider(). Please help here

i am using below gradle dependency
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-iot-device-sdk-java:1.3.11'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iot:1.12.506'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have a role alias created and have you added the assumeRoleWithCertificate policy to your device policy so it can use the role mentioned in the role alias?